# Node.js and Javascript; Proper use case of Getter and Setter methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node & JavaScript and was using the framework of a getter and setter to accomplish this task.

In `gs.js` I am reading the contents of a SQL file where I want to read the file and put it in a string so from my `reader("SELECT * FROM INVENTORY", [])` I can do `reader(selectFrom("Inventory.sgl"), [])`. Looking at it from a getter and setter aspect I would use the set method to set the variable of the file name and the get method to return the select statement.

Basically is this the proper method to accomplish this? I have asked this question before but it got off topic of the file reader and should it be file reader sync. Being this is server side only, my books say it does not have to be with the sync method. Really this is more of an exercise to help me get a better understanding so if anyone can assist that would be create.

**gs.js**

```
var sys = require('sys');
var fs = require('fs');

function selectFrom(sqlFile, selectStatement) {
    this.__defineGetter__('sqlFile', function() {
        console.log("Getting file " + sqlFile + " to select from.");
        console.log('About to read file.');
        var fileName = "./SQLs/" + sqlFile;
        fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log("There was a problem opening " + sqlFile + "\nDetials:" + err);
            console.log("OK: " + fileName);
            selectStatement = data;
        });

        return sqlFile;
    })

    this.__defineSetter__('sqlFile', function(arg) {
        sqlFile = arg
    })
}

var selectFrom = new selectFrom("on.sql")
console.log(selectFrom.sqlFile);

module.exports.selectFrom = selectFrom;
```

**ora.js**

```
connection.setPrefetchRowCount(50);
var reader = connection.reader(selectFrom(Inventory.sql), []);

function doRead(cb) {
    reader.nextRow(function(err, row) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        if (row) {
            console.log("got " + JSON.stringify(row));
            return doRead(cb)
        } else {
            return cb();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I personally would be a little reluctant to perform IO calls using a getter. I'd prefer to have a function with a name that reminds me that I'm performing a heavier operation. But that's just me.

Comment: ...also, I'm sure this is just an example, but with `var selectFrom = new selectFrom("on.sql")`, you're overwriting your `selectFrom()` function.

Comment: ...however, since you seem to be asking for opinions, I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: ...last of all, `__defineGetter/Setter__` are non-standard syntax. There's an official ECMAScript 5 syntax you should perhaps use instead. It'll definitely work in NodeJS.

Comment: I would also suggest that a getter and setter operate on a single property.  It kind of sounds like you want a stateful object with a query property that gets set by an IO operation.  Delegete the IO operation to another funciton/object and pass that value into the constructor of your object... if that's what you're trying to do

Comment: Yes this is just an exercise for me cookie..

Comment: I have a basic understanding, books like smashing node.js, sams teach yourself node and express in action do a great job on outlining the framework. But very little on coding, javascript books do a good job on the code but don't touch on node so this is really my only outlet. I think I suffer from a little OCD because until I get this to work it will consume me.

Comment: user3391179 I would say yes this would be a query property but I do not think by IO operation, I can use it as a command line util to move data from one db to another.

Comment: I think I know what the issue is if someone can confirm, really it is my lack of understanding at this time but because node js is an event loop var never gets assigned, need to study on async!

Comment: In your question you said 'I have asked this question before but it got off topic of the file reader and should it be file reader sync' - but that is not off topic - it is probably why you aren't getting the results you want. More generally, I agree with cookie monster though that this not something for which getters are intended to be used. I know you are doing it as 'an exercise' but that doesn't mean you shouldn't try to do exercises correctly.